Detectar doble pulso o codigo con esp32 y RcSwitch
Estoy tratando de utilizar un control rf433 con un esp32 y la libreria rcswitch, puedo obtener los codigos de cada boton pero quiero detectar ciando se pulse 2 veces un boton en menos de 1s o cuando se pulse por mas de 2s. Ya intente varias formas pero no lo logro.
cuando sea doble guardar 229
      byte receivedCode;
    
        void setup() {
          mySwitch.enableReceive(15);
        }
    
        void loop() {
        rfData();
              switch (receivedCode) {
                case 0xE1:
                  manageLocks(closeLocks);
                  break;
                case 0xE2:
                  manageLocks(openLocks);
                  break;
                case 0xE3:
                  Serial.print("Doble pulso ");
                  break;
         }
        }

    void rfData() {
      if (mySwitch.available()) {
        // Obtiene el código recibido
        int receivedValue = mySwitch.getReceivedValue();
        receivedId = (receivedValue >> 8);      // Extraer ID
        receivedData = (receivedValue & 0xFF);  // Extraer Data (como E2)
        unsigned long currentTime = millis();
        if (currentTime - lastPulseTime > debounceDelay) {
          lastPulseTime = currentTime;
          bool autorized = isAutorized(receivedId);
          if (autorized) {
//DETECTAR SI SE PULSA 2 VCES
            receivedCode = receivedData;
          }
        }
        mySwitch.resetAvailable();
      }
    }


Imagino que cuando se mantiene pulsado emite el código en ráfaga, si cada vez que lo recibes sumas un contador y anotas el tiempo del primer código recibido, luego cuando el tiempoActual - tiempoPrimerCodigoRecibido sea mayor a 2 segundos miras cómo va el contador y si pasa de X número es que ha mantenido pulsado supongo que serviría para detectar pulsaciones prolongadas si el sistema no tiene algún otro mecanismo para ello. Lo mismo te sirve para detectar un doble pulso en realidad, determinas un tiempo límite para que cuente como doble y no dos simples, y si el contador es 2 ya lo tienes.
